# PebbleKit JavaScript send image to Pebble

Tags: javascript, image, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Is it possible to send a images to the Pebble watch using PebbleKit Javascript sendAppMessage.

My idea is to load an image from the web and send it to the watch and display them there. If an image is not possible directly then I was thinking of drawing the image to a canvas and trying to get bitmap data from the canvas to send to the watch.

Is any of this possible now or am I thinking of things that have not been done yet. If possible how? If not done yet how might you do it?

Looking to brainstorm and share possible code ideas.

I should also mention that I do not want to use an iOS or Android app, only the PebbleKit JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a complete example of an app that uses JavaScript to download images in the [pebble-hacks](https://github.com/pebble-hacks/) Github repository. This github projects hosts different non-official yet written by team pebble.

The one you are looking for is [pebble-faces](https://github.com/pebble-hacks/pebble-faces). The image download part is built in a [separate source file](https://github.com/pebble-hacks/pebble-faces/blob/master/src/netimage.c) to be easily re-used in your own project.

Comment: This assumes the server is providing .pbi images which limits a number of scenarios.  I'd love to see some example javascript code that converts an html <canvas> to .pbi format (probably using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData)

Comment: I tried that but could not get it to work because the JavaScript engine used by Pebble on iOS (Ejecta) does not support creating canvas object when it's running headless.

Comment: Thanks for trying :)  What do you think about adding a function to the PebbleKit API that calls into the native Pebble app to do the conversion?  Anything that gets rid of having to do the conversion serverside would open up a bunch of doors (at least for me)

Comment: It's on the wishlist!

Comment: What is a .pbi image? searching online is not giving me much. If I have .png or .jpeg images is there a converter to create .pbi images?

Comment: @ryuutatsuo It's causing me a nightmare. `.pbi` is bit per pixel monochrome - 1=>White, 0=>Black. Padded to 32bits wide. That JS sample is practically useless - if you had the .pbi ready on a server you may as well load into Pebble resources.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added a comment in the README file on how to prepare pbi file: https://github.com/pebble-hacks/pebble-faces/ - Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, thank you @sarfata. There wouldn't be a batch process for the pbi files?

Comment: You can easily build a shell command - something like: for i in \`ls *png\`; do python Pebble/tools/bitmapgen.py pbi $i $i.pbi; done

Comment: Here is the batch shell I came up with can be easily changed. 

#!/bin/bash
for f in /Users/dir/Downloads/*.png
do
  filename=$(basename "$f")
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  filename="${filename%.*}" 
  echo "$f ----> /Users/dir/Downloads/$filename.pbi"
  python /Users/dir/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0.1/Pebble/tools/bitmapgen.py pbi $f /Users/dir/Downloads/$filename.pbi
done

Answer (score 0):

I also added a PHP port for the Python script here 
https://github.com/logbon72/pebblebitmap

It might come in handy if your run PHP applications that need to do conversion on the fly.